Datasource Micrometer not working with opentelemetry zero-code instrumentation
I am using the zero-code instrumentation Java agent in order to export traces from my Spring Boot app to Jager in otlp format. So far so good, but i need more than the autoconfiguration provided by default by it.
Is there any other way to configure the jdbc instrumetation using the java agent to display when the actual transaction started and commited/rolled back?
(I am interested in seeing more than the basic spans that correspond method calls inside my handler methods)
As written in the documentation, I supposed that setting otel.instrumentation.micrometer.enabled = true will allow me to export traces using datasource-micrometer-spring-boot.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
